# Samsung Galaxy S3 stock email app - Load more details

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I use the S3s stock email app for my Hotmail account, but I haven't been able to find a setting to allow the emails to be automatically loaded in HTML view.  For each email I have to scroll to the bottom of the email and select "Load more details", then the email loads in HTML and all the hyperlinks are converted to graphics.

On my old Evo there was a setting where I could choose to receive emails as text or HTML, but I haven't been able to find that setting in the stock email app on the S3.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "Message format" setting located at **Settings > [account] > Sync settings > Message format**. The choices available are "HTML" and "Plain text." Not sure whether that will necessarily solve your particular problem, but perhaps try giving that a shot.

Comment: While this did not resolve my issue, trying to follow your directions made me realize I didn't have the options you listed above.  So I deleted my hotmail account from the app and set it up new, however this time I didn't choose the default "exchange" option, but instead did a manual setup and chose POP3 ... that fixed it!  Thank you for your reply.